# Embedding matplotlib in tkinter: figure shifts around when you mouse over

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Edit: I figured it out! I'll put my solution in the answers in case someone else makes the same careless mistake as me. :)

I'm having some trouble embedding a Matplotlib figure in my Tkinter gui. Here is the snippet of code I use to create the figure:

```
def create_plt(self, images, labels):
    num = len(images)

    fig = Figure()
    axes = fig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num)
    for ind, img in enumerate(images):
        axes[ind].imshow(img)
        axes[ind].set_title(labels[ind])

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.itemframe)
    canvas.draw()

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.itemframe, pack_toolbar=False)
    toolbar.update()

    toolbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
    widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    widget.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

All this code is supposed to do is add subplots of the images/labels I pass in side-by-side, so that the user can zoom in and out of these images and pan around.

[image]

It looks alright at first, but when I mouse over it after selecting the pan or zoom tool, the entire plot shifts wildly, resizes itself, the toolbar disappears, and is generally buggy.

[image]

I suspect that I'm packing something incorrectly, but I can't tell what. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the frame, `self.itemframe`, that I was trying to place the widget in was the wrong size. It was too small--around 400x300, when the size of the widget was much larger, so it kept having to resize itself every time the GUI updated and appeared glitchy.
Fixed it by instantiating `self.itemframe` with a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the DPI of the figure. Once I set it back from 80 to 100 it was working normally. No more glitching.